# From SQL select to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

My previous `SQL SELECT` code worked with this AJAX request, but I want to convert it to PDO statements.

#### JavaScript

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "ajax.php",  
    data: "mail="+ mail,  
    success: function(msg){  
    if(msg == 'mail already in use'){
    ....
```

#### ajax.php

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vedic;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);

if(isset($_POST['mail'])){
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

$stm = $pdo->prepare("select id from members where email='$mail'");
$stm->execute(array($id));
$name = $stm->fetchColumn();
```

What now? How can I get the result which I can use in AJAX?

Comment: what is the current output you get from ajax.php?

Comment: Have you read up on how parameterized queries work? [This is an excellent tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). You'll need to use a `?` or `:mail` placeholder instead of `$mail`.  And what is `$id`? You have not defined it - probably you meant to use `$mail` there.

Answer (score 4):

You are supposed to *understand* what you are reading, not just copy-paste it.
Look what have you read:

> Using prepared statements is the main reason to use PDO.
>   **Every dynamic data literal has to be represented in a query by either name (:name) or regular placeholder (?).**

But what did you do? Kept your data inserted in a query directly:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("select id from members where email='$mail'");
```

Why not to make this code using placeholder?

> and what now ?

Fix your code to make it sensible and working.

> How can I get the result which I can use in ajax?

The code you posted is *already* supposed to take the desired value, which you can use anywhere you wish.

Please take a little time investigating this code, playing with it, making yourself familiar with it. Bear in mind that this site is not a free coding service. A code from answer is not necessarily have to be working out of the box. An answer supposed to give you an *idea*, not do your job.

Comment: @SunSky There is a lack of *reality checks* on stackoverflow recently. This answer is correct and explains you step by step how to solve the problem. Isn't it nice enough? that's probably because there are already hundreds of questions like this.